# How can I add a new attribute to a RestKit-mapped object after object creation from JSON?

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit

Here's my scenario:

1. I get a JSON list from an API call, and use a RestKit mapping to generate the associated objects, with Core Data backing.
2. I then use a property on one of these objects (= parent) to generate a new (and separate) API call to get a different JSON list from which I map different (= child) objects.
3. Each of these children needs a reference (e.g. ID) to the parent object, but this reference is not included in the JSON payload.

So my question is: how do I access these child objects post-mapping, to make sure the field referencing their parent is specified? I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face somewhere in the RestKit documentation, but that's an enormous haystack and I'm not sure where to start looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the identity of the parent is part of the URL used to obtain the children then you can use RestKits routing mechanism, together with path patterns, to obtain all of the required data and connect the objects automatically during mapping. This uses the `RKRouter` and `RKRelationshipMapping` classes.

Check the section on 'Routing' [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html) for a good description and several examples.

Alternatively, every method that loads a URL and performs a mapping has a completion block which gives access to the mapped objects. This is usually an instance of `RKMappingResult`, from which you can get a dictionary, or array, of the mapped objects.

Once you get the objects you can modify them and then simply save the managed object context.

Comment: Thanks Wain. Do you have any examples of the first approach you suggest? As regards the second approach, if I mess with the array of mapped objects provided in the completion block, does it automatically update the Core Data store?

Comment: Fantastic - thanks. Second approach worked like a charm; I'll get round to implementing the first when I feel a bit more confident with RestKit.